# How to invoke a post when using HubController<T>?

Tags: signalr

I can't find much documentation on the new `HubController<T>` so maybe I'm going about this wrong. This is what I have:

```
public class StatusController : HubController<StatusHub>
{
    private string _status = "";

    public string Get()
    {
        return _status;
    }

    public void Post(string status)
    {
        _status = status;

        // Call StatusChanged on SignalR clients listening to the StatusHub
        Clients.All.StatusChanged(status);
    }
}

public class StatusHub : Hub { }
```

This is how I'm attempting to create the hub proxy:

```
var hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://localhost:51076/");
var statusHubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("StatusHub");
statusHubProxy.On<string>("StatusChanged", status => Console.WriteLine("New Status: {0}", status));
await hubConnection.Start();
```

How do I call the Post method of my controller? This is where I'm getting an exception:

```
await statusHubProxy.Invoke("Post", "Test Status");
```

Comment: Can you please post the full details of the exception you are getting (i.e. exception.ToString())?

Comment: I've come to the conclusion that the HubController is simply for allowing access to the Clients from within the controller. To invoke a post on the controller, the client could use a HttpClient, not the hub proxy.

Comment: I've got a console application that uses a HubProxy to send messages to a website, no issues there for me with using the Proxy. I am not using a HubController on the web end though, so perhaps that is the difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HubController<T>` just provides some basic plumbing that gets you access to the resources that are associated with the specific hub type (e.g. `Clients`) that you want to work with. Calling it has nothing to do with invoking the actual hub itself, so you don't use the hub client API, it's just straight HTTP calls. Without `HubController<T>` you would have to reach out to SignalR's `GlobalHost.Configuration.GetHubContext<T>()` yourself to find the `IHubContext` for your hub type.

So, you can call your `StatusController::Post` method with any of the standard .NET HTTP APIs: `HttpClient`, `WebClient` or `HttpWebRequest`.